Inequalities on a biconditional and how to include the case that holds with equality?
How would you compactly present these two results?
For all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ $3x-3\geq 0$ if and only if $x-1\geq 0.$
For all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ $3x-3 = 0$ if and only if $x-1 = 0.$
Is there a compact way of writing "For all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ $3x-3\geq 0$ if and only if $x-1\geq 0,$ and $3x-3 = 0$ if and only if $x-1 = 0.$" ?

By assuming the mathematical fact $$\forall z{\in}\mathbb R\,(z>0{\implies} z\ne0),$$ your results are mathematically equivalent to

For each real $x,$ $$(3x-3 = 0\iff x-1 = 0) \text { and }(3x-3>0\iff x-1>0).$$

If we continue applying mathematics, then we will just end up with the logical validity (first-order tautology)

For each real $x,$ $$(x=1\iff x=1) \text { and }(x>1\iff x>1).$$


I wonder if the OP was looking for a way of writing the conjunction without an explicit use of "and"? I can't think of a reason why the OP would want to do this (indeed, this seems like an XY Problem to me), but perhaps something like would work: "For each $x \in \mathbb R,$ the sign of $3x-3$ is the same as the sign of $x-1.$" (with the understanding that $0$ is assigned both the $+$ sign and the $-$ sign)

@DaveL.Renfro Yes, your summary works too, though it does rely on an additional mathematical fact: $\forall z{\in}\mathbb R,(\lnot z≥0{\iff} z<0).$ The more mathematical axioms we invoke, the more we can condense the original results—until we eventually end up with a first-order tautology like in my final sentence above. So, yes, I'm smelling XY too...
